# Android Search in Fragment

Tags: android, search, fragment, refresh, adapter

My project structure is

1. Main Tab Activity with a searchView, a ViewPager and a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
2. FragmentStatePagerAdapter generates a Fragment for each ViewPager .
3. Every fragment has ExpandableListView and BaseExpandableListAdapter.

How to submit a query text to refesh the fragment?

Comment: Why not create a base abstract Fragment that each of your Fragments can inherit from which each override a method refresh(String textFromSearch) (or whatever you want) that is defined in the abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks for Guardanis' suggestion, it works!

1.Create a method in the base Fragment.

```
public void updateView(String searchQuery)
{
    View rootView=getView();
    expListViewPriceList = (ExpandableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExpPriceList);
    listAdapter=new PriceListAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),this.productCategory,searchQuery);
    expListViewPriceList.setAdapter(listAdapter);       
}
```

---

2.In the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, I also create a method to get the right fragment.

2.1 Declare a Map to store Fragments

private Map mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap();

2.2 Put the Fragment instance into the map

mPageReferenceMap.put(Integer.valueOf(index), priceListFragment);

2.3 create a method to get the right fragment

```
public PriceListFragment getFragment(int key) {     
    return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
}
```

---

3.Get the right fragment to call updateView().

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String keyword) {

            mAdapter.getFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).updateView(keyword);   
            return false;
        }
```

---

Reference

1.http://tamsler.blogspot.tw/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html

2.http://android-flash-cards.googlecode.com/svn/tags/blog-20111123/src/org/thomasamsler/android/flashcards/CardsPagerActivity.java